# Find position of word/substring in string (python 3.4.3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, position, substring

I want to find the position of the **WHOLE** word in the string, but my code displays the position of the first character of the word.

```
string = input("Please input a sentence: ")
word = input("Please input a word: ")
string.lower()
word.lower()
list1 = string.split(' ')
position = string.index(word)
print (position)
```

Comment: please, clarify that

Comment: Specify which language you're using and then I'll identify which question this duplicates :-)

Comment: I'm a beginner in coding so I'm sorry if it's not correct but if by language you mean program, I'm using Python 3.4.3 Shell

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: yes :-) i changed the string.index(word) to list1.index(word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking the word as an input, you have the word size and you know the starting index, you could do: starting index + size.

```
string = input("Please input a sentence: ")
word = input("Please input a word: ")
string.lower()
word.lower()
list1 = string.split(' ')
position = string.index(word)
print (position) // starting position
print (position + len(word) ) // end position
```